# How to solve error: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, xml

I have seen that there's been some similar questions but the answers to those haven't helped me so far. The full error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View)
>   in a parent  or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined
>   on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   'button_random'

The class (**StartActivity.java**):

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "CLICKED " + v.getId());
    }

}
```

The XML (**activity_start.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Game"
        android:id="@+id/button_random"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have added the activity to the AndroidManifest.xml. I have similar activities that work in the same way and I don't have any problems with those...

Does anyone see something where I am missing something or have made a mistake?

Comment: Your error message refers to `AppCompatButton`. You are not using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: I tried something before posting, apologies. I´ve edited the code above to reflect my current code. With both options it doesn´t work btw.

Comment: Your error still says AppCompatButton, but your question doesn't include one

Comment: Yes cricket_007, that is correct and part of the reason why I am baffled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case, I changed `Button` in XML to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` and it worked.

Code with Error:

```
 <Button
        .... />
```

Fixed Code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        .... />
```

Comment: Nope, not working as of today, I already was using `AppCompatButton`

Answer (score 13):

In my case I missed closing bracket at the end.

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> CommentHandler.selectGallery(v)"
```

It should be like this.

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> CommentHandler.selectGallery(v)}"
```

Comment: brooo, you saved my day

Comment: Thank you.  One would think AS would show the error.

Answer (score 6):

Please rename `onClick` method to anything other than that, Android thinks you are calling the internal `onClick` from `View.java` exposed via `OnClickListener` interface

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Random Game"
    android:id="@+id/button_random"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="myOnClick" />
```

and in your Activity

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        }

        public void myOnClick(View v) {
          Log.d("DEBUG", "CLICKED " + v.getId());
        }
}
```

You can check the View documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Game"
        android:id="@+id/button_random"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I have 2 activities using the same layout so when I changed the `OnClick` event name it will crash in other activity try to check the `setContentView` layout in the crashing activity