# Instant run working but after building apk and installing on phone , it is crashing

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Im trying to build an app. Now i am testing it but it is working fine when running by pressing run button. Also run using adb is also working. But when i generate apk, that app is crashing on button click

I want to see my layout in my friends phones. I cant use adb.

My logcat shows this error . Please help

```
`06-24 21:51:53.773 8883-8883/com.example.ebin1.temp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ebin1.temp, PID: 8883
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'g5'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6176)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)`
```

Comment: Someone please comment

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve error: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136574/how-to-solve-error-could-not-find-method-onclickview-in-a-parent-or-ancestor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this error by adding `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` instead of `Button` in the xml file